# C++ Vector of vectors, cannot edit

Tags: c++, vector

I have a MatrixGraph class with a member variable M that is of type `vector<vector<double> >`. I have a constructor that takes in an unsigned, and makes a NxN matrix from that input, and I want to initialize it to zero. The problem is when I run my code the debugger kicks in when I am trying to assign stuff. I have tried to methods, the first:

```
MatrixGraph::MatrixGraph(unsigned num_nodes) {
for(int i = 0;i < num_nodes;i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j < num_nodes;j++) {
        M[i][j] = 0.0;//breaks on this line
    }//end i for loop
}//end j for loop
}
```

and the second method i tried i found on here but that didn't work either:

```
MatrixGraph::MatrixGraph(unsigned num_nodes) {
for(int i = 0;i < num_nodes;i++) {
        M[i].resize(num_nodes);//breaks on this line
    }
}
```

i commented on here where the last line on the call stack is before i get errors. The next line after that on the call stack shows me the class vector and is saying that my Pos is greater than the size of my vector. I assume that this is a size zero matrix, but i don't know why i cant make it bigger. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: why not 'i' and 'j' also be unsigned as 'num_nodes' is unsigned? Better still use size_t

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code is failing is that you **cant use the [] operation** on a vector **before that element exists**. The usual way to add a value to a vector is to use **push_back**.

If you want to initialize to 0 you want **assign**(). Resize the outer vector to the required size and then assign each of the inner vectors with 0

```
M.resize(num_nodes);
for(int i = 0;i < num_nodes;i++) 
{        
    M[i].assign(num_nodes,0.0f);
}//end i for loop
```

This can also be done. It is cleaner code but a tad less efficient since it makes 1 extra vector object.

```
vector<double> temp;
temp.assign(num_nodes,0.0);
M.assign(num_nodes,temp);
```

or just

```
M.assign(num_nodes,vector<double>(num_nodes,0.0));
```

neatest one(courtesy @Mike Seymour) would be

```
MatrixGraph(unsigned num_nodes) 
   : M(num_nodes, vector<double>(num_nodes,0.0)) 
{}
```

(thanks Mike Seymour for the constructor syntax)

What you are doing here is initializing the outer vector with a temp vector full of `0.0`s

Answer (score 2):

You need to populate your vector M with data: `M.resize(num_nodes)`

This should do it:

```
MatrixGraph::MatrixGraph(unsigned num_nodes) 
{
    M.resize(num_nodes);
    for(int i = 0;i < num_nodes;i++) 
    {
        M[i].resize(num_nodes);
        for(int j = 0;j < num_nodes;j++) 
        {
            M[i][j] = 0.0;
        }//end j for loop
    }//end i for loop
}
```

Comment: Or, if you're not being paid per line of code, `MatrixGraph(unsigned n) : M(n, vector<double>(n)) {}`